# Light to frequency converter TSL235R with Beaglebone Black and Python

Tags: python, beagleboneblack

I am using TSL235R (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9768) with Beaglebone Black(BBB). Unfortunately, I couldn't find a tutorial how to use this sensor with BBB and python and wrote my own script but either wiring is incorrect or the scripts has mistakes - the output data doesn't change when I vary light intensity. I need to get irradiance value(which is an average of 100 values) every second. Here is my script:

```
import Adafruit_BBIO.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setup("P8_11", GPIO.IN)

# area of TSL235R in cm2
area = 0.0092 

while True:     
    for n in 100:
        f = []
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(100):
            GPIO.input("P8_11")
        duration = time.time() - start                                                                                       
        frequency = 100 / duration                                                                                                       
        irradiance = frequency / area
        f.append(irradiance)
    avg = sum(f)/len(f)
    print " irradiance is {}".format(avg)
    time.sleep(1)
```

Wiring:

```
TSL235R     BBB
1-GND  =>   P9_1           
2-VDD  =>   P9_5
3-OUT  =>   P8_11
```

Any comments and suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be measuring the frequency at all

```
start = time.time()
for i in range(100):
    GPIO.input("P8_11") # reads the input state, but discards the result
duration = time.time() - start                                                                                       
frequency = 100 / duration                                                                                                       
irradiance = frequency / area
```

Perhaps you meant to do something like (untested):

```
state = GPIO.input("P8_11") # read current input state
while GPIO.input("P8_11") == state:
    pass # wait for input to switch
start = time.time()
while GPIO.input("P8_11") != state:
    pass # wait for input to switch again
duration = time.time() - start # this is the duration of half of the waveform period
```

Note: the BBB might be too slow to measure the higher frequencies that the device outputs, so you may get bad readings at some light level. Whether it is suitable for your application or not will depend on exactly how fast the input read is and what your maximum light level is reaching the sensor. You could consider reducing the total light getting to the sensor (via a pin hole say) to bring it back into a usable range.

**EDIT**

Also, have you connected pins 1-GND and 2-VDD to ground and positive on the BBB, or are they using GPIO lines too?

**EDIT 2**

Here's an example measuring multiple pulses in an attempt to improve accuracy

```
num_pulses = 10 # make this longer for more accuracy
state = GPIO.input("P8_11") # read current input state
while GPIO.input("P8_11") == state:
    pass # wait for input to switch
start = time.time()
for i in range(num_pulses):
    while GPIO.input("P8_11") != state:
        pass # wait for input to switch again
    while GPIO.input("P8_11") == state:
        pass # wait for input to switch again
duration = time.time() - start # this is the duration of num_pulses pulses
period = duration / num_pulses
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am new to electronics, so I am not surprised that I did something wrong. I connected pins 1-GND to ground and 2-VDD to positive which , according to this source http://stuffwemade.net/post/beaglebone-pinout, corresponds to P9_1 and P9_5, respectively.

Comment: @chemist No problem. Yes that wiring looks correct based on your link. Let me know how it goes once you get a chance to test it

Comment: It looks like your method is working but to be honest, I still cannot get how to measure the frequency properly. My understanding is that TSL235R outputs a square wave (50% duty cycle), to simplify - 50% on and 50% off. So, do I need to calculate the frequency of one whole period (on and off) or the frequency of just one state(either on or off)? Also, how to get more or less consistent data? Currently, the frequencies I get are too noisy under the same light conditions. Thank you!

Comment: @chemist Correct, this is only measuring half of the period so the duration should be doubled before calculating the frequency. I would say that as the BBB is not running a real time operating system it will struggle with this type of measurement - you'd be better off with a microcontroller (eg Arduino). You could improve your results though by measuring multiple pulses instead of just one - I'll edit the post with an example.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code! I really appreciate your help!!! I do have Arduino but I am building a detector that heavily relies on Python (that's why I chose Beaglebone Black) and I would prefer to stick to BBB. I will play with number of pulses to get more consistent data. Again, thanks for the help!

Comment: @chemist you might want to consider using a different sensor that doesn't output frequency then - does the BBB have analog inputs? That might be a good option

Comment: Yes, BBB has analog inputs. I need to measure the change of light intensity of a led(s)(region 380 - 700 nm). Initially I used a photoresistor as described here https://learn.adafruit.com/measuring-light-with-a-beaglebone-black/overview but I was not satisfied by results. I found an article that describes similar measurements to what I am trying to get and there a light to frequency converter TSL230 was used. That's why I decided to try TSL235r.

Comment: @chemist Maybe look at something like the [Adafruit TSL2561](http://www.adafruit.com/product/439) which communicates via i2c and doesn't depend on the host being realtime. Here is a forum post describing using it with a Raspberry Pi and BBB: http://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&p=242826

Comment: Thanks for the information. I will take a look at this sensor. There are many tutorials on how to use TSL235r with Arduino, so maybe I will connect Arduino to BBB and will "catch" Arduino's data using Python via serial port.